# gthumb 3.0.1 - how to view, empty Trash?

Tags: gthumb

When I am browsing images with gthumb 3.0.1, hitting the DELete key removes the file from the browser (I assume by placing it into a gthumb Trash), but it remains on disk.  And there appears to be no way to either view the gthumb Trash nor empty it.

How does one view and/or empty the Trash - removing the files from the disk - in gthumb?

Answer (score 1):

In `gthumb 3.0.1` (and in any earlier versions) pressing delete on the keyboard brings up the dialogue in the screenshot below (*Are you sure you want to move  to trash?*).
This trash folder is not a gthumb hidden folder, but is just the particular user's trash folder (`/home/mike/.local/share/Trash/files`), which is more easily accessible with a file explorer such as `Nautilus`. So if you load up `Nautilus` and go to the trashcan, your pictures should be there.

[image: gthumb 3.0.1]